# Internet Explorer 9 beta HTML5 video tag not supporting relative width/height?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, html5-video, internet-explorer-9

Is it correct that IE9 (Beta & Preview) don't support relative width/height on the html5 video tag?

Chrome, Safari & Firefox all nicely accept a width=50%, but IE9 seems to read it as 50px. (Video is showing in all 4 browsers so no problem there).

I was wondering if it's a bug/feature yet to be implemented or permanent solution.

J.

Comment: "video is showing in all 4 browsers" -- well, I'm impressed with you managing just that much, given all the charades around video formats. Have you checked it still works in non-Windows browsers (Mac, Linux, iPad, mobiles...)

Comment: I've checked on Mac, works also. It's an mp4 with ogv and webM fall back. Haven't tried to flash-fall-back for older browsers or mobile since IE9's being stubborn...

Comment: See Spudley's and dudeman's answer. Percentage values in the height and width attributes are not valid in HTML5, so since `<video>` is new in HTML5, there's really no reason for IE9 to support them. Percentage heights and widths are plainly styling, and therefore should be supplied using CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting the height and width using CSS rather than the HTML element's attributes?

ie rather than:

```
<video src='whatever' height='50%' width='50%'>
```

you could try:

```
<video src='whatever' style='height:50%; width:50%;'>
```

...or, of course, put the styles into your separate CSS file.

Comment: As a note, the W3C spec says that the height and width attributes should both be in pixels, just as with the <img> tag. Using percentages is technically invalid, and makes a lot more sense anyway to put that information in CSS.

Comment: Thanks, did the trick. 
Even though as Alohci commented above it's a style thing and it should be applied to CSS, it's still a break from the other browser's behaviors/implementations.

Comment: @jbokkers - IE9 may be a big improvement over its predecessors, but that doesn't mean it's going to be perfect. In the time it's taken them to take IE9 from pre-release to release candidate, they've already begun to fall behind the competition. I foresee a future where IE is still the lame duck of the browser world.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed the IE9 Release Candidate and since there's no change I guess we can call this their permanent solution.

Just to be complete: `<video width="100%" height="100%"></video>`

Will render as 100px width in IE9. In latest versions of Chrome, FireFox, Safari and Opera this will be rendered 100% width of the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

I used CSS to style the  tag for width:100% and height:100%. I tried IE9 Beta and that seemed to work.